# I am asked to find the equation of tangent to the curve $y=\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi x^3}{6}\right)$ at $x=1$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I am asked to find the equation of tangent to the following curve at $x=1$:
$$\displaystyle y=\sin^2\left(\frac{\pi x^3}{6}\right)$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=2\sin\left(\frac{\pi x^3}{6}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\pi x^3}{6}\right)\frac{3\pi x^2}{6}$$

Evaluated at $x=1$ $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{4}$ Also $y_{x=1}=\frac14$

So equation of tangent should be $y-\frac14=\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{4}(x-1).$

This question came in an exam  , and the answer given is $y-\frac14=-\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{4}(x-1)$

Where am  I going wrong?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2780881/find-the-tangent-to-the-curve/2780894#2780894

Comment: I get the same equation as you!

Comment: @labbhattacharjee : I understand why you gave that reference, but the cited question's answers are non-responsive to the actual question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computation is correct, and the answer given by your teacher in incorrect.

This kind of computations can be checked using Wolfram Alpha, with the input

> tangent line of y=Sin[Pi*x^3/6]^2 at y=1

Comment: thank you............